# Are Dot product and Multiplying matrices are same when coming to arrays of two different dimensions in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I observed a wierd output while taking dot product of two vectors. My code was

```
a1 = np.array([[1], [2], [3]])
a2 = np.array([[1, 2, 3]]) 

print(a1*a2)
print(np.dot(a1, a2))
```

**The outputs for both are same** and I dont understand why it multiplies two matrices when asked for dot

product. And the same is observed for **any matrices with shape (x, 1) and (1, y)**.

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In numpy, `dot` doesn't really mean dot product. `dot` essentially behaves like matrix multiplication. One might therefore argue it is both superfluous and confusingly named which is why I myself do not use it at all.

To get the behavior you seem to want you can use `vdot` instead:

```
>>> np.vdot(a1,a2)
14
>>> np.vdot(a2,a1)
14
```

Answer (score 3):

```
In [189]: a1 = np.array([[1], [2], [3]])
     ...: a2 = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4]])
In [190]: 
In [190]: a1.shape, a2.shape
Out[190]: ((3, 1), (1, 4))
```

Matrix multiplication:

```
In [191]: a1@a2                # np.matmul
Out[191]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 2,  4,  6,  8],
       [ 3,  6,  9, 12]])
```

Broadcasted elementwise multiplication:

```
In [192]: a1*a2
Out[192]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 2,  4,  6,  8],
       [ 3,  6,  9, 12]])
```

(3,1) with (1,4) => (3,4) with (3,4) => (3,4)

Size 1 dimensions are adjusted to match the other array(s)

Same as `matmul`:

```
In [193]: a1.dot(a2)
Out[193]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 2,  4,  6,  8],
       [ 3,  6,  9, 12]])
```

Mismatched shapes:

```
In [194]: a2.dot(a1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-194-4e2276e15f5f>", line 1, in <module>
    a2.dot(a1)
ValueError: shapes (1,4) and (3,1) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 3 (dim 0)
```

With einstein notation:

```
In [195]: np.einsum('ij,jk->ik',a1,a2)
Out[195]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 2,  4,  6,  8],
       [ 3,  6,  9, 12]])
```

In true matrix multiplication this multiplies all rows by all columns, summing on the shared dimension.  Because the `j` dimension is 1, the summing doesn't make a difference.

We can see the effect of broadcasting with:

```
In [198]: np.broadcast_arrays(a1,a2)
Out[198]: 
[array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3, 3]]),
 array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
        [1, 2, 3, 4],
        [1, 2, 3, 4]])]
```